# Asynchronous methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asynchronous

I have two Async tasks (A & B) which upon completion will invoke the callback method passed. I want to wait till both complete and be able to perform another task C using the results of tasks A and B.

How can this be accomplished? Is there a standard way of doing this?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem for example via Threading, but in C# you have techniques to implement this other ways. Therefore you have to use Delegates and an asynchronous method call.

Here is a link from Microsoft Support - if you are an experienced C# programmer you could scroll down and read the samples, else if i would recommend to read the full article.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582
(sample 3 could solve your issue).

Answer (score 2):

Use [Task.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) to wait tasks A and B completed.

Example:

```
 var A = new Task<string>(DoA);
 var B = new Task<string>(DoB);

 A.Start();
 B.Start();

 Task.WaitAll(A, B);

 var C = new Task(() =>
                         {
                             string resultA = A.Result;
                             string resultB = B.Result;

                             //Do something more;
                         }
                    );
 C.Start();
```

Comment: WaitAll will pause the current method.  It's anti-Async.

Comment: What would you suggest instead of using WaitAll in .NET 4.0?

Comment: I would suggest WhenAll and ContinueWith, see my answer.

Comment: WhenAll is just available in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

use [Task.WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374) and [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696)

```
var taskA = new Task<string>(DoA);
var taskB = new Task<string>(DoB);
var taskC = new Task<string>( () => DoC(taskA.Result, taskB.Result));
var taskCheckPoint = Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB);
var taskFollowUp = taskCheckPoint.ContinueWith(taskC);
taskA.Start();
taskB.Start();
//now we return, instead of waiting.
```

---

If you don't have .net 4.5, then you have to use some form of Wait.  You may not want the Task creating method to wait, so have taskC wait instead:

```
var taskA = new Task<string>(DoA);
var taskB = new Task<string>(DoB);
var taskC = new Task<string>( () =>{
  taskA.Wait();
  taskB.Wait();
  DoC(taskA.Result, taskB.Result)
});
taskA.Start();
taskB.Start();
taskC.Start();
//now we return, instead of waiting.
```